# How to trim input field value in struts?

Tags: struts

I use Struts v1.3 and have following input form:

In struts-config.xml:

```
    <form-bean name="testForm" 
               type="org.apache.struts.validator.DynaValidatorForm">
        <form-property name="displayName" type="java.lang.String" />
    </form-bean>
```

In validation.xml:

```
    <form name="testForm">
        <field property="displayName" depends="required">
            <arg key="input.displayName" />
        </field>
    </form>
```

How do I trim value of "displayName"? How do I trim values of all "java.lang.String" input fields of the form?

Answer (score 2):

You may have a chance to trim the string right at the moment, the request processor updates the data from the input fields to the form. This was not tested, but what happens when you modify the setter setDisplayName(String displayName) to something like

```
public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
    this.displayName = displayName.trim();
}
```

This is not a very good solution, because it migrates logic into a setter.

regards

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use trim for **validation** purposes, I think the proper way is to create and use your own (or extend an existing) validator for required fields that takes trim into consideration.
For an example, you can use this page: http://struts.apache.org/1.2.4/userGuide/dev_validator.html, the section "Pluggable Validators".

If you want to use trim for trimming the String values before **using them in your business logic**, you can extend *org.apache.struts.validator.DynaValidatorForm* and overwrite the methods that retrieve values, like *get(String name)*, *getString(String name)* and so on. After that, you use your class in the *form-bean* declarations.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having String manipulation logic in your Form class, you can try the StringUtils methods in Apache's Commons Lang JAR:

[StringUtils JavaDoc](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html)

This will let you trim your Strings in a number of specific ways, whether you want to trimToEmpty, trimToNull, etc.  This means you have access to null-safe methods, which can be useful with some values.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively try using javascript regexp in the jsp that will trim onfocus or onblur

> < html:text name="testForm" property="displayName"   onfocus="javascript:this.value=this.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'')" onblur="javascript:this.value=this.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'')" />

Comment: This seems really really verbose and error prone and easy to forget.  I agree it works, but trimming in the form setter or even in the action seems better to me.